# Can I set an alternative vendor target folder path for a composer package from GitHub?

Tags: git, composer-php

I'm attempting to pull a package from GitHub, where we have our private repository, but I'd like to change the "vendor/package" folder name when it is required - namely because:

1. we couldn't get our official company name as our GitHub account
2. as we're not going via composer, we name our packages with prefixes in an attempt to keep them organised

PEAR has a `vendor-alias` key, which Git does not seem to, but in essence, I'm wondering if something like this is possible:

composer.json:

```
"require": {
    "timeslice/common": "~1.0"
},
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url":  "git@github.com:timeslicelive/kiosk-common.git",
        "vendor-alias": "timeslice/common"
    }
]
```

Install path:

```
/vendor/timeslice/common/
```

Comment: I'm also interested in an answer to this question. In my use case I have forked a GitHub repo to our company repo, and the company repo path does not follow the `vendor/project` convention, so I tried to override it with `vendor-alias` but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: No answers yet, but I'm wondering if Toran Proxy might be a solution: https://toranproxy.com/

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with a package supporting up to laravel 5.2 and I have laravel 5.3.

Of course composer throws a dependency error:

```
Problem 1
  - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.3.19
...
  - pqb/filemanager-laravel 2.0.7 requires illuminate/support 5.0.*|5.1.*|5.2.*
```

The package author have not updated to laravel 5.3 and the github issue message about the update was for about a month unresponded.
I find a github fork that it was updated to support laravel 5.3, so I needed to make composer use the original package name, but to install the forked updated version of the sources.

The oudated repo is: https://github.com/guillermomartinez/filemanager-laravel

The updated repo is: https://github.com/LuaxY/filemanager-laravel

The package at https://packagist.org is: https://packagist.org/packages/pqb/filemanager-laravel

So, I wanted to have a package in `pqb/filemanager-laravel` with the source of the updated `LuaxY/filemanager-laravel` github repo.

The `package` type defined in `repositories` (`composer.json`) worked for me:

**Note**: in order to autoload the package, you need to specify the auto load directory of the package. It can be `src`, `dist` or even something else. You should always check the repo directory structure.

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "package",
        "package": {
            "name": "pqb/filemanager-laravel",
            "version": "2.0.7",
            "dist": {
                "url": "https://github.com/LuaxY/filemanager-laravel/archive/5.3.zip",
                "type": "zip"
            },
            "source": {
                "url": "https://github.com/LuaxY/filemanager-laravel.git",
                "type": "git",
                "reference": "pqb/filemanager-laravel"
            },
            "autoload": {
                "classmap": ["src"]
            }
        }
    }
]
```

and in the require section we include the original package:

```
"require" : {
    "pqb/filemanager-laravel": "^2.0.7"
}
```

Then I did a `composer update` and I got the package installed from the github repo with no dependency errors:

[image]

Comment: That's super-interesting. Not sure when I can check it out as I'm on a new project right now, but I will, hopefully sooner rather than later!